# Preventing form submission based on conditions

Tags: jquery, forms, preventdefault

I have built a form validator using Jquery that prompts the user the password requirements and if they have satisfied them when they key on to the password form. This code is working as I would like and is shown below:

### form validation

```js
 $('input[type=password]').keyup(function () {
        // set password variable
        var pwd = $(this).val();
        //validate the length
        if (pwd.length < 8) {
            $('#length').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check valid').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check invalid');
        } else {
            $('#length').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check invalid').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check valid');
        }
        //validate capital letter
        if (pwd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
            $('#capital').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check invalid').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check valid');
        } else {
            $('#capital').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check valid').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check invalid');
        }

        //validate number
        if (pwd.match(/[0-9]/)) {
            $('#number').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check invalid').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check valid');
        } else {
            $('#number').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check valid').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-check invalid');
        }

    }).focus(function () {
        $('#pwd_info').show();
    }).blur(function () {
        $('#pwd_info').hide();
    });

});
```

**Now**, I would like to prevent the button from being submitted before these requirements have been met and I have added the following function to my document trying to do so:

### Stop form submission

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#signup_btn').submit(function (e) {
        var pwd = $('input[type=password]').val();
        if (pwd.length < 8) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (pwd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (pwd.match(/[0-9]/)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } 
else
            return true;



    });
```

When I attempt to submit an invalid password based on my conditions (1 number, 1 capital, and min 8 characters) it is still allowing me to go through. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your `else` statement only corresponds to the last `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to capture the `submit` event, perform your validation, and `return false` if there are any validation failures.

```js
$('#signup_btn').submit(function(e) {
  var err = 0;
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() { 
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      err = 1;
    }
  })
  if (err != 0) {
    console.log('errors');
    return false;
  }
  console.log('submitted');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signup_btn">
  <input type="text" placeholder="needs text">
  <input type="text" placeholder="needs text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This will call an infinite loop no ? You submit the form, and you prevent it to submit.

Comment: @VincentDecaux doh, you're right! wrote it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#signup_btn').submit(function (e) {
    var pwd = $('input[type=password]').val();
    if (pwd.length < 8) {
        return false;
    }
    if (pwd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (pwd.match(/[0-9]/)) {
        return false;
    }   
else
        return true;



});
```